ContractContainer still empty in Brownie after contract Deployment
Please I know this question might be a repetition of what was previously asked here but the answers didn't solve my problem.
In my case I actually used the brownie run scripts/deploy.py --network sepolia prompt to deploy my contract to the sepolia network.
This is my deploy.py file.
from brownie import accounts, config, SimpleStorage, network
import os


def deploy_simple_storage():
   account = get_account()
   simple_storage = SimpleStorage.deploy({"from": account})


def get_account():
   if network.show_active() == "development":
      return accounts[0]
   else:
      return accounts.add(config["wallets"]["from_key"])


def main():
    deploy_simple_storage()

I see the deployed contract in my .build/deployments folder. But when I try to interact with it in my read_value.py file, I get a IndexError: list index out of range error.
This is my read_value.py file.
'''Interacting with contracts deployed inside our brownie project'''

from brownie import SimpleStorage, accounts, config, network
from brownie.network.contract import ContractContainer


def read_contract():
    print(SimpleStorage[0])


def main():
    read_contract()


Please I'll need your help. Thanks.

Are you also passing --network sepolia flag while interacting with your read_value.py script?

Thanks @SYEDASADKAZM it worked!

Make sure that you pass --network sepolia flag while interacting with your read_value.py script too.
